# Flask view creates DataFrame but still raises "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'df' referenced before assignment"

Tags: python, pandas

I cant find problem with variables registration.

`Jinja2` show me:

> builtins.UnboundLocalError UnboundLocalError: local variable 'df'
>   referenced before assignment

When I try add: **global df** after function definition Flask told me that `variable is not definied.`

```
@app.route("/<stop_id>")
def show_table(stop_id):
    stops = pd.read_csv('stops.csv', header=0, usecols=[1, 2])
    chosen_stop = stops['stop_name'] == stop_id
    output_stops = (stops[chosen_stop])
    stop_codes = tuple(output_stops['stop_code'])
    for i, j in enumerate(stop_codes):
        specific_url = URL + str(j)
        response = requests.get(specific_url, auth=HTTPDigestAuth(USERNAME, PASSWORD), verify=False)
        if len(response.content) > 0:
            data = response.json()
            df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='columns')
    return render_template('view.html', tables=[pd.DataFrame.to_html(df, index=False)])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

HTML:

```
<div class=page>
  <h1>Project</h1>
  {% for table in tables %}
    {{ table|safe }}
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that df is undefined is because it is undefined at the scope you are trying to use it. You create the df variable at this line

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='columns')
```

But this df variable is a variable that will only be accessible to anything within the if statement.

```
if len(response.content) > 0:
    data = response.json()
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='columns')
```

Try the following which simply changes the scope of the variable to be accessible to the render_template function you are calling.

```
@app.route("/<stop_id>")
def show_table(stop_id):
    stops = pd.read_csv('stops.csv', header=0, usecols=[1, 2])
    chosen_stop = stops['stop_name'] == stop_id
    output_stops = (stops[chosen_stop])
    stop_codes = tuple(output_stops['stop_code'])
    df = None
    for i, j in enumerate(stop_codes):
        specific_url = URL + str(j)
        response = requests.get(specific_url, auth=HTTPDigestAuth(USERNAME, PASSWORD), verify=False)
        if len(response.content) > 0:
            data = response.json()
            df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='columns')
    return render_template('view.html', tables=[pd.DataFrame.to_html(df, index=False)])
```

However you should probably do some kind of check to see if the value of df is `None` and then return a different template like an error page or something.